# product not show in category page in magento 2.0.2

Tags: magento2, product, category, magento-2.0.2

I am create a new theme but products are not showing in category page but while i will using Magento Blank theme products are showing please help me.

Comment: Did you figure it out ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to remove var folder from root and try commands using cli:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Clear browser cache and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rakesh's answer: Also, make sure that product status is "Enabled" (you can make a bulk action in admin panel to enable all products in the category list)